# Python: Generate string variables based on number with the same value as the number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to Python and maybe my question is a simple one, but I tried to search it on the internet and I couldn't find a solution.

I need to generate variables with a name xxx+number with the same value as the number. Final result should be to create a list of variables like this:

```
xxx1 = 1

xxx2 = 2

.
.
.

xxx999 = 999
```

That way I can use those variables for the rest of the code. I tried with "for i in range(999):" and then tried .append, str(i) or similars with no success.

Comment: Why not use a list?

Comment: Why would you do such a thing really ?

Comment: I found the solution:  
  for i in range(1, 999, 1):  
     globals()['xxx%s' % i] = i